# cannot read property 'length' of undefined for shopping cart component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a shopping cart component and trying to format the cart layout. I just want to see the layout of the cart so I commented out the products component which should get me the cart layout alone, so I can see what it looks like and what's going on, however I keep getting the following error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" when I try to compile it in react.

My shopping cart component code:

```
import React from "react";
import { Container, Typography, Button, Grid } from "@material-ui/core";
import useStyles from "./styles";

const Cart = ({ cart }) => {
  const isEmpty = !cart.line_items.length;
  const classes = useStyles();
  const EmptyCart = () => (
    <Typography variant="subtitle1">No items selected</Typography>
  );

  const FilledCart = () => (
    <>
      <Grid container spacing={3}>
        {cart.line_items.map((item) => (
          <Grid item xs={12} sm={4} key={item.id}>
            <div>{item.name}</div>
          </Grid>
        ))}
      </Grid>

      <div className={classes.cardDetails}>
        <Typography variant="h4">
          Subtotal: {cart.subtotal.formatted_with_symbol}
        </Typography>
        <div>
          <Button
            className={classes.emptyButton}
            size="large"
            type="button"
            variant="contained"
            color="secondary"
          >
            Empty Cart
          </Button>
          <Button
            className={classes.checkoutButton}
            size="large"
            type="button"
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
          >
            Checkout
          </Button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );

  return (
    <Container>
      <div className={classes.toolbar} />
      <Typography className={classes.title} variant="h3">
        Your Shopping Cart
      </Typography>
      {isEmpty ? <EmptyCart /> : <FilledCart />}
    </Container>
  );
};

export default Cart;
```

The error is specifically on the line:

```
const isEmpty = !cart.line_items.length;
```

Also my App JS code:

```
mport React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Products, Navbar, Cart } from "./components";
import { commerce } from "./lib/commerce";

const App = () => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  const [cart, setCart] = useState({});

  const fetchProducts = async () => {
    const { data } = await commerce.products.list();

    setProducts(data);
  };

  const fetchCart = async () => {
    setCart(await commerce.cart.retrieve());
  };

  const handleAddToCart = async (productId, quantity) => {
    const item = await commerce.cart.add(productId, quantity);

    setCart(item.cart);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchProducts();
    fetchCart();
  }, []);

  console.log(cart);

  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar totalItems={cart.total_items} />
      {/*<Products products={products} onAddToCart={handleAddToCart} /> */}
      <Cart cart={cart} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

There is no `cart.line_items` on the initial render since initial state is an empty object (`{}`).

```
const [cart, setCart] = useState({});
```

## Solution

Provide valid initial state for the initial render so there's a truthy, defined `cart.line_items` object from which to have a `length` property, i.e. so `!cart.line_items.length;` can resolve to a value and not throw an error.

```
const [cart, setCart] = useState({ line_items: [] });
```